# Multiple values in a row

Tags: entities

How do I get multiple values (from one field) in a row in the node template? I have a field where a user can select up to 3 values. I would like that to be displayed this way:

> Industry: industry1, industry2, industry3

I don't want it displayed like this:

> Industry: industry1
>             industry2
>             industry3

I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please post the html structure? We can do it in different way from css(content) to jquery (.after()/.before())

if it's a list you can use

```
$('ul.YOURCLASS li a:not(:last)').append(', ');
```

width the css:

```
li:after
{ 
content:", ";
}
li.last:after{
  content:none;
}
```

Comment: <div class="field field-type-image-image field-field-product-image">
  <h3 class="field-label">Image</h3>
  <div class="field-items">
      <div class="field-item"><?php print $node->field_product_image[$node->language][0]['safe_value']; ?></div>
  </div>
</div>

Answer (score 3):

If it's just adding the commas to an array, PHP has `implode()`.

```
implode(', ', $fields).
```

I think iRex is asking how to get the values. In this case, I would use the following code.

```
$fields = array();
foreach ($node->field_name['und'] as $field) {
  $fields[] = $field['value'];
}
```

Comment: You are right Joe. I'm practically useless with PHP though, and I was looking for the correct syntax

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this in a field template.

If your field is called tester, the template would be called field--field_tester.tpl.php, and it would have code similar to this (assuming the field is a text field):

```
<?php 
  foreach($items as $values => $item) {
    print render($item['#markup']) . ",&nbsp;";
    }
?>
```

Doing it in a field template lets you manipulate the field as requirements demand, without messing around with the rest of the node's output format.

Comment: Perhaps I should have mentioned that I'm using Drupal 7. I was trying to display multiple values from a (multiselect) field in a row. I tried using this in a node--mycontenttype.tpl - I hid, then displayed the unchanged multiple values, but came short when tring to rearrange them in a row... 

<?php foreach ($item as $values => &item) {
 print render($item['product_image']); }?>  
//returns a blank.  So does the following 

<?php foreach ($item as $values => &item) {
 print render($content['product_image']); }?> // What am I missing?

Comment: As I suggested, rather than formatting the individual field in the node--mycontenttype.tpl.php template, you can leave the node alone and instead write a field template field--field_fieldname.tpl.php. That will format only the specific field and leave everything else alone.

See the code in my answer, above, for a way to output the field values as comma-separated items all on one line.

Comment: Got it! thanx! This did the tricK:-   <?php 
  foreach($items as $values => $item) {
    print render($item) . ",&nbsp;";
    }
?>

Answer (score 1):

There is also a module for that: [Field Delimiter](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_delimiter)

> Field Delimiter provides an additional setting for field formatters, allowing multi-value fields to be displayed with a delimiter between the values.